# using Excel Workbooks.OpenXML and getting a warning that stops the automation

Tags: c#, excel, automation, dataset

Excel 2010.

I have a C# app that has a dataset with multiple tables. I want to export this to a workbook where each table is a separate sheet it is important to keep the order of the datasets, and the name of the data tables)

One possible solution is to loop through each table, put it on its own dataset, save this dataset as XML, then use the Application.Workbooks.OpenXML method

[MSDN OpenXML Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.openxml.aspx)

But here is the problem, if I pass the third parameter (which gives a very nice import with filters and everything), excel succeed, but it warns me that some columns were imported as text, which is ok with me (one of the columns is UPC, which should be a text, not a number).

By displaying this message it stops the process until the user clicks that this is acceptable. Then I question my self about how the mother of all excels is doing these days.

How to prevent this message from popping up?
Or another way to do this import with such nice results? (Copy and paste works but not so nicely, writing in every cell using automation is way to slow, maybe using some excel library...)

You turn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var excelApplication = new Application { DisplayAlerts = false };
```

or

```
Workbook excelWorkBoook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(...);
excelWorkBoook.CheckCompatibility = false;
```